# Applying makefile in a nested directory and mirror that structure

Tags: makefile

I have a folder for notes called `md` which can have nested folders inside. I have written a python script to convert a markdown file into a html file and fix links etc. It can be invoked by running the command `python3 md2html <markdown_file> <output`*`file>`. I also made a python script which basically does a tree traversal on the `md` directory, and invokes this `md2html` program on each markdown file in this directory (ignoring other filetypes), and builds a corresponding html directory like so.

```
.
|-- html
|   |-- mydir
|   |   |-- one.html
|   |-- apps.html
|   |-- c_assignment.html
|   |-- ewd35.html
|-- md
|   |-- Makefile
|   |-- mydir
|   |   |-- lorem.html
|   |   |-- lorem.ms
|   |   |-- lorem.ps
|   |   `-- one.md
|   |-- apps.md
|   |-- c_assignment.md
|   |-- ewd35.md
|   |-- ewd35.pdf
```

I recently learned about Makefile, and to my understanding I can make it so that the `md2html` program is only run on `md` files that have been modified since the last time their corresponding `html` file was created. I am struggling to understand how I can write a Makefile to replicate the structure of the `md` directory, as it is fixed. I searched and I saw that recursive Makefiles are not a good idea so I am asking here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin, you don't specify which variant of `make` you are using.  You'll need GNU Make to be able to do this.  Standard POSIX `make` cannot do it.

First, you need to find all the `.md` files.  You can either list them explicitly, which means you'll need to update your makefile when you create (or delete) `.md` files:

```
MD_FILES := ./mydir/one.md ./apps.md ./c_assignment.md ./ewd35.md
```

Or, you can have make find them itself.  If you don't want to assume anything about the data structure you can have it invoke `find` to do it for you:

```
MD_FILES := $(shell find . -name \*.md)
```

Next you convert those pathnames to be the ones you want to create:

```
HTML_ROOT := ../html
HTML_FILES := $(patsubst ./%.md,$(HTML_ROOT)/%.html,$(MD_FILES))
```

Now you write a target that depends on the HTML files that need to be created:

```
all: $(HTML_FILES)
.PHONY: all
```

(you can use any target you want, it doesn't have to be `all`... just make sure it comes as the first explicit target in the makefile).

Finally, write a pattern rule that tells make how to build one `.html` file from one `.md` file:

```
$(HTML_ROOT)/%.html : %.md
        mkdir -p $(@D)
        python3 md2html $< $@
```

See the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) to understand what these special variables mean.

And you're done!  GNU Make will figure out which `.html` files are outdated and run the recipe here for each one.

Comment: Thank you very much, this was so helpful and worked perfectly! I really appreciate you taking the time to write such a comprehensive and beginner friendly answer :)